# Why kill a timer from within the timer callback?

Tags: winapi, timer, callback

In Raymond's [example](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20041015-00/?p=37553) of how to use `SetTimer` to distinguish single and double-clicks, he calls `KillTimer` from within the timer callback function.  I wasn't clear on why that would be necessary.  Doesn't the fact that the callback is occurring mean that the timer has reached its endpoint?

Comment: Because if you don't call `KillTimer`, the timer never ends, and will call the callback function again and again, each `GetDoubleClickTime` milliseconds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oddly enough, the documentation for [SetTimer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-settimer) doesn't document its behavior. The behavior being that the call installs an auto-repeat timer.

However, you will find the following under [timer operations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/about-timers#timer-operations):

> Whenever the time-out value for the timer elapses, the system posts a [WM_TIMER](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/wm-timer) message to the window associated with the timer.

This API has no immediate support for one-shot timers. To implement a one-shot timer you have to call [KillTimer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-killtimer) when handling the first `WM_TIMER` message.

Answer (score 0):

Timers fire repeatedly at their specified frequency. You must call `KillTimer` if you wish them to stop firing.

So a classic usage is to create a timer, and then kill it the first time it fires. That's known as a one shot timer.